# Problem regarding group action

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G=Gl_n(\mathbb F_p)$, and let $H$ be a subgroup of order a power of  $p$. Prove that $\exists v\neq 0\in V = {\mathbb F_p}^n$ such that $h(v)=v$ $\forall h\in H$.

My approach: We know that $G$ acts on $V$ in the obvious way. Then, $|V| =$sum of cardinalities of orbits. We have to show that one of the orbits has cardinality equal to 1. I tried to use the class equation, but cannot reach to a contradiction assuming the contrary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can $v$ be the zero vector?

Comment: no it can't... I forgot to put that. I have edited the question now.

Comment: This is actually a general fact when a finite $p$-group acts on a vectorspace over a field of characteristic $p$ (the field need not be finite and the vectorspace need not be finite dimensional). The general argument is a bit more involved than the answer by Boris Novikov (though it is still fairly elementary). I will add an answer with it when I get the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G$ acts on $V\setminus 0$ and $|V\setminus 0| = p^n-1$.  Orders of all orbits divide $|G|$. Hence at least one orbit has order $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the more general version. The proof is a lot longer than the very nice one by Boris Novikov (and I am almost certain that his solution is the one intended for this exercise), but it still does not use any big machinery.

First, a couple of nice lemmas that are good to know anyway.

Lemma 1: Let $G$ be a finite group that acts on the vectorspace $V$ via linear maps (so for each $g\in G$ the map $v\mapsto g.v$ is a linear map $V\to V$).
Then there is a finite dimensional subspace $W\subseteq V$ such that for all $w\in W$ and all $g\in G$ we have $g.w\in W$.

Proof: Let $v\in V$ be any non-zero vector and let $X$ be the $G$-orbit of $v$. Now $X$ is a finite set since $G$ is finite, and the subspace of $V$ spanned by $X$ satisfies the desired conclusion (easy exercise).

Lemma 2: Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and assume that $G$ acts on a set $X$. Let $X^N = \{x\in X\mid \forall h\in N,\, h.x = x\}$.
Then for all $g\in G$ and all $x\in X^N$ we have $g.x\in X^N$. Further, if $X$ is a vectorspace and $G$ acts via linear maps, then $X^N$ is a subspace of $X$.

Proof: Let $g\in G$, $h\in N$ and $x\in X^N$ be given. We need to show that $h.(g.x) = g.x$ (since this is what it means for $g.x$ to be in $X^N$. The left side is clearly $(hg).x$, so write $(hg).x = (gg^{-1}hg).x = g.((g^{-1}hg).x)$. Now, by normality of $N$, $g^{-1}hg\in N$, so since $x\in X^N$ we have $(g^{-1}hg).x = x$ and hence $g.((g^{-1}hg).x) = g.x$ as desired.
The second statement is an easy exercise using that since $G$ acts via linear maps, so does $N$.

Now we are ready to prove the general version.

Proposition: Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group acting via linear maps on a vectorspace $V$ of dimension $\geq 1$ over a field of characteristic $p$ (neither the field nor the dimension of $V$ are assumed finite).
Then there is a non-zero $v\in V$ such that for all $g\in G$ we have $g.v = v$.

Proof: First, we note that Lemma 1 allows us to assume that $V$ is in fact finite dimensional anyway (since otherwise, we just restrict to the subspace given by that lemma and once we find a vector there with the desired property, this works for the entire space).
The proof will be by induction on $|G|$, and if $|G| = 1$ then the result is trivial.
Now, pick a $g\in Z(G)$ of order $p$. The action of $g$ on $V$ is given by some matrix $A$. Now, since $g^p = 1$ we also have $A^p = I$ ($I$ being the identity matrix), and hence $A^p - I = 0$. But since the characteristic of the field is $p$ the same is true of the ring of matrices over the field (I am ignoring what the actual dimension of $V$ is as it is not important), so this means that $A^p - I = (A - I)^p = 0$ and hence the matrix $A - I$ is not invertible. This means that $A$ has an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, and hence there is a non-zero vector $w\in V$ such that $g.w = w$. Note that if we now let $N = \left<g\right>$ then $w\in V^N$ (notation as in Lemma 2), so the subspace $V^N$ has dimension $\geq 1$ and by Lemma 2, $G$ acts on it via linear maps. But since we also have that $N$ acts trivially on $V^N$, we get that $G/N$ acts on $V^N$ via linear maps (just by defining $(gN).v = g.v$), and hence by our induction hypothesis, there is a non-zero $v\in V^N$ such that $(gN).v = v$ for all $g\in G$, and this means precisely that $g.v = v$ for all $g\in G$, which was what we wanted to show.